# Input field max value validation server response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I have a React function that saves grades in MongoDB cluster. However, it saves any value, but I want only values between 1 and 10 to be saved, if value is out of this interval, I would like to display an alert and don't save grade in database.

Here is my function:

```
const saveGrade = async (id, value, idGrade) => {
try {
  setLoading(true);
  setSuccess(false);
  setError("");
  let resp = null;
  resp = await axios.post(`subjectGrade/create`, {
    subjectStudent: id,
    partial: semester,
    grade: value,
  });
  if (value <= 10 && value >= 1) {   \\here im adding the range i want
    if (resp.status === 200) {
      setSuccess(true);
      const ids = dataUserSubjects.reduce((ids, item) => {
        if (item.subject._id === subjectAssigned) ids.push(item._id);
        return ids;
      }, []);
      const getSubjectGrades = async () => {
        const gradesSubject = await axios.post(`/subjectGrade/all`, {
          ids,
        });
        setStudentsGrades(gradesSubject.data);
      };
      await getSubjectGrades();
    } else {
      setError(resp.data.msg);
    }
  } else {
    alert("NOT OK");  \\here i display an alert, but value is still saved in database

  }
} catch (err) {
  setError(err.message);
}
setLoading(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what axios.post(`subjectGrade/create`) does but I think you should nest this block of code in the if statement:

```
    if (value <= 10 && value >= 1){
      let resp = null;
      resp = await axios.post(`subjectGrade/create`, {
        subjectStudent: id,
        partial: semester,
        grade: value,
      });
      if (resp.status === 200) {
      ...
```

if not please give more detail.